# problem with creating dropdown within flexbox navigation bar, the dropdown content can't be displayed normally

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been having trouble positioning and displaying dropdown menu below the navigation bar which is styled with flexbox, it appeas that the dropdown menu that overflows out of the flex container is hidden, even though it was given position: absolute and z-index. [dropdown menu hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y410u.png) [vertically display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QNco.png) please help me and take a look at my code.

```
    <ul class="topNav" id="myTopNav" role="navigation">
        <li>shopping bag</li>
        <li>sign in</li>
        <li class="all_categories">          
          <ul class="categories">                
            <li class="category-women">
              <a href="#">women</a>
              <ul class="sub-category">
                <li><a href="#"> New in!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Tops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Coats & Jackets</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="category-men"><a href="#">men</a></li>
            <li class="category-home"><a href="#">home & gift</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The .topNav is the flex container is styled like this:

```
.topNav {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
  padding-bottom: 0.6%;
  border-bottom: #c9c8c7 0.02em solid;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The links inside navigation bar are displayed as block;
here's my code for the drop down menu:

```
.category-women{
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.sub-category {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.sub-category a {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 8px;
  background-color: green;
}

.category-women:hover .sub-category {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Any chance of a **demo** of this issue. But I notice that you didn't set a width on the submenu.

Comment: I'm very new to this I think I need some time to figure out how to upload a demo here... the width of the submenu is not fixed, it's supposed to vary according to width of its son elements, the submenu itself is also a flex container